# Herança no models do flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

Como faço para uma classe herde outra classe no models do flask?

estou criando a seguinte classe User em meu models

```
lass User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "users"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String)
name = db.Column(db.String)
email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
tipo = db.Column(db.String(1))

#tipo: N - nutricionista, P - paciente, A - admin  

@property
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

@property
def is_active(self):
    return True

@property
def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

def get_id(self):
    return str(self.id)

def __init__(self, username, password, name, email, tipo):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.tipo = tipo

def __repr__(self):
    return "<User {0}>".format(self.username)
```

Até ai beleza, quando vou criar a classe Paciente que deveria herda User já que o paciente sera um usuário, os campos do Paciente vão parar no User

```
class Paciente(User):
__tablename__ = "pacientes"

dataNascimento = db.Column(db.DateTime)
sexo = db.Column(db.String)
cidade = db.Column(db.String)
profissao = db.Column(db.String)
celular = db.Column(db.String)
objetivo = db.Column(db.String)

def __init__(self, username, password, name, email, dataNascimento, sexo, cidade, profissao, celular, objetivo):
    super().__init__(username, password, name, email, "P")
    self.dataNascimento = dataNascimento
    self.sexo = sexo
    self.cidade = cidade
    self.profissao = profissao
    self.celular = celular
    self.objetivo = objetivo

def __repr__(self):
    return "<Paciente {0}>".format(self.username)
```

Não surge nenhum erro, porém depois que dou o migrate e upgrade a tabela Paciente não é criada e o User herda os campos de Paciente

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que usar o recurso [Polymorphic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=polymorphic) do SQLAlchemy

Adaptei seu código em um único "arquivo" para exemplificar o funcionamento, é só copiar, alterar as configurações de conexão com o banco de dados e executar.

```
from flask.app import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://<user>:<password>@<host>/<databasename>?client_encoding=utf8'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    tipo = db.Column(db.String(1))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':tipo
    }
    #tipo: N - nutricionista, P - paciente, A - admin  

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User {0}>".format(self.username)

class Paciente(User):
    __tablename__ = "pacientes"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    dataNascimento = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    sexo = db.Column(db.String)
    cidade = db.Column(db.String)
    profissao = db.Column(db.String)
    celular = db.Column(db.String)
    objetivo = db.Column(db.String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':"P",
    }

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Paciente {0}>".format(self.username)

class Nutricionista(User):
    __tablename__ = "nutricionistas"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':"N",
    }

def __repr__(self):
    return "<Nutricionista {0}>".format(self.username)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    pac = Paciente(username="joao", email="joao@gmail.com")
    nutri = Nutricionista(username="ana", email="ana@gmail.com")
    db.session.add(pac)
    db.session.add(nutri)
    db.session.commit()
    print(db.session.query(User).all())
```

DICA: No trecho de execução (__main__), você irá notar que usei as classes específicas de cada tipo para criar as instancias, se seu objetivo é usar o atributo `tipo` você pode usar o padrão factory para tal.